# Can I use x86 OS in other archtectures i.e.: ppc?

Tags: linux, architecture

I want to install slackware x86 in a ppc pc? Can I do it?

If not, if I compile only the kernel to ppc, may it work?

Are There any ways to accomplish this??

thaks for all answers!
and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: When i was using slamd64, i could install x86 32bits and x86 64bits on the same os, why i cant make this in ppc?

Comment: x86_64 is a superset of x86 (kinda).  It's possible to run x86 code on x86_64.  PPC is wildly different.  You cannot run code compiled for x86 on PPC.

Comment: FYI, you need to study up on what an ISA is a bit before you think about this.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't.  You need code compiled for PPC.

The [Slackintosh](http://workaround.ch/) project is based on Slackware, but for PPC.  You may want to check them out.

Comment: SlackIntosh is very old, and i want to use x86 slackware repository, no other way to make this?

Comment: No, you cannot use the x86 repository; at least not the compiled binaries, they will not execute on PPC.  You would need to compile everything from source.  There are modern PPC distros you could use instead - Fedora and Debian for example maintain current PPC releases (http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-ppc and http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a kernel compiled for x86 on a different architecture, because the other architecture has a different set of instructions. It is almost like trying to compile a Java program with a C++ compiler on a lower level.

You can compile the kernel for the new architecture, but you'll also need the other executables you're going to run on top of your kernel for your new architecture.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an emulator like [qemu](http://www.qemu.org/) or [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) to install a second OS (for a different CPU) on your existing OS. That allows you to use the second OS and all apps that were made for it.

The only other alternative is to compile everything again for your new CPU because CPUs can't learn foreign languages.

Comment: No, you can't! Emulators cannot emulate a complete different chipset! At least not without a huge performance loss.

Comment: VirtualBox and VMWare are NOT emulators - they allow you to run a virtual machine inside your host OS, but they run the guest OS natively (using hardware virtualization support in the CPU if available). You cannot use this to emulate an entirely different CPU architecture.

Comment: That was true in 1999 but we've gone some way since them. You can run a JIT compiler on the code, for example. You can replace known code pieces with calls to functions in the real OS.

Comment: @Jesper: bochs is a soft emulator which works anywhere.

Comment: @Aaron, I can't discover where Bochs claims it supports the PPC, although it does mention that it's build in C++ and therefor it could be compiled on a PPC system. Even if this would be true, I would think the performance would still be real bad because of the multiple OS layers plus the in-between emulator. Even with a JIT compiler, it would still be slow.

Comment: He wanted to run x86 code on a PPC and that's what bochs can do. Bochs itself isn't very fast but that doesn't mean all emulators are slow. For example, Amithlon could run Amiga code faster on a standard PC than any Amiga you could build. So it's more a question "How fast is your emulator" vs. "How fast is the original system" plus "How badly you need the application". If your life depends on running the app, speed is not the main issue. In this case, even a very slow emulator is better than nothing.

Comment: qemu emulates an x86 system on ppc just fine, and much faster than bochs, because qemu does dynamic cod translation/recompilation and bochs is a straight interpreter.

Comment: @ephemient: Thanks for reminding me. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

PPC and x86 use two very different instruction sets. PPC processors do not even implement much of the functionality of a modern x86 CPU because PPC processors only offer a reduced instruction set.

Pretend you've bought a brand new mobile phone, but it is in a language you can't understand, and the supplied instruction manual is for a completely different brand and model. That is what x86 Slackware will look like to a PPC.